# org 0C700h gives weird output

Tags: assembly, linker, bootloader

I'm writing a bootloader but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct. First, I'm using this batch script to compile my bootloader:

```
dm\bin\dmc.exe -msdo -c -cpp bootloader.cpp
masm\bin\ml.exe -c bootloaderASM.asm
dm\bin\link.exe /BINARY bootloaderASM.obj bootloader.obj
```

I'm using DMC's compiler and linker, along with masm 615 assembler, they all SHOULD be 16 bit (DMC is both 16 and 32).
Now in my assembly file bootloaderASM.asm, if i add "org 07C00", the output file bootloaderASM.sys becomes filled with 0's until 07C00, then the expected code is filled in. However, if i remove it, the output file is as expected.
As I understood, the org instruction simply adjusts addresses used by my instructions so that the base is 07C00, I suppose it shouldn't fill up my output files with zeros?

The .obj files from the compiler and assembler seem to be OK. They don't contain leading zeros until 0x07c00, but the final output from the linker is what's wrong.

Now is the problem with the linker? how can i fix it/do you suggest a different(16 bit) linker? Also - is it OK if i simply ignore the org instruction for my bootloader?

Also - I have written a program to read my bootloader and write it in the boot sector of a virtual hard drive, I can simply modify it to ignore the leading zeros in the linker output - would that work?

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't use Digital Mars' linker, but perhaps the `/BASE` and `/FIXED` switches could accomplish what you want (combined with `ORG 0`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So I'm not sure how the /FIXED option helps but if i use /BASE:31744 (07C00 in decimal) would that make it ok to have org 0 in the bootloader?

Comment: The base address should be given in hex, not decimal. Whether it will work or not, I don't know since I haven't used it. I only suggested it as something you could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understood, the org instruction simply adjusts addresses used by
>   my instructions so that the base is 07C00, I suppose it shouldn't fill
>   up my output files with zeros?

According to the [NASM Manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.1.1), the MASM implementation of [`ORG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kacdf0c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) actually moves subsequent outputs to the given offset.

As for your observation, since there might be codes from other modules before that point, the .OBJ file merely stores the offset, expecting the linker to position it properly, in the case by simple padding.

> Now is the problem with the linker? how can i fix it/do you suggest a
>   different(16 bit) linker?

The linker is not at fault here. It is a quirk of MASN acting up.

> Also - is it OK if i simply ignore the org instruction for my
>   bootloader?
>
> Also - I have written a program to read my bootloader and write it in
>   the boot sector of a virtual hard drive, I can simply modify it to
>   ignore the leading zeros in the linker output - would that work?

From reading OSDev Wiki, both may well work, provided that segment registers are handled accordingly. My understanding is that the output should be placed in position `0` in the hard disk partition and to be loaded into offset `0x7c00`. As long as it runs according to this specification, it "should work".

The following might provide further helpful reading:

MASM `SEGMENT` ( msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06y3478%28v=vs.80%29.aspx ) directive in a related post ( stackoverflow.com/questions/12552072/masm-segment-directive )

PS. (I "need at least 10 reputation", which I don't have considering this is my first post, " to post more than 2 links". )